# Copy files to a folder structure based on format of the file name

Tags: file, copy, structure, directory

I have millions of pdf files that are in the naming format:

```
PropertyRef - Address - TypeofCertificate.pdf
```

For example:

```
1568740494443 - 45 Whitegate Ave - Electrical.pdf
1568740494443 - 45 Whitegate Ave - Fire.pdf
1568740494443 - 45 Whitegate Ave - Gas.pdf
```

I need to copy/move these into a folder structure which is already set up and the folder structure in place is as follows:

```
S:\Properties\1568740494443 - 45 Whitegate Ave
```

Then, within this folder are the folders Electrical, Fire, Gas.

Could someone assist me in creating some kind of batch script that would allow me to do pick up the file from a folder on a `D:` drive, then analyse the first part of the file name, and then copy the file into the relevant electrical, gas or fire folders?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this pretty simply with python. Checkout os.walk and os.rename, see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html). Here is some starting code:

```
import os
#root prints out directories only from what you specified
#dirs prints out sub-directorie# from root
#files prints out all files from root and directories

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("path\to\your\dir"):
    for f in files:
        sfile_name = f.split('-')
        print os.path.join(root, f)  # old
        print os.path.join("S:",  "Properties", sfile_name[0] + "- " + sfile_name[1].strip(), sfile_name[2].strip())  # new
        #os.rename(old_path, new_path)
        #...
```

Good Luck.